# Apply custom settings within Android

Tags: android, kotlin

For a kiosk application I would like to hide or disable some settings within the device. For example, I want to turn off the WiFi so that it cannot be turned on anymore. Disable the developer options so that it can no longer be enabled. And make various options within settings no longer visible.

Can this be arranged via a policy within android or do I have to make a custom rom for this?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is impossible unless you are having your own custom Android OS and your application was being installed on that specific OS. This level of massive access is not provided by the default variant of Android to developers.